# the default xml namespace of the project must be the msbuild xml namespace c#

Tags: c#, xml

Help please I tried to delete one package from my project and after that all my packages got yellow triangle after that I closed the project project not unload when I tried to Reload it , it gives me this error .

```
Project Name : kudim.
Visual Studio : 2015.
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <EnableUnmanagedDebugging>false</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>
    <EnableSQLServerDebugging>false</EnableSQLServerDebugging>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishUrlHistory>publish\</PublishUrlHistory>
    <InstallUrlHistory />
    <SupportUrlHistory />
    <UpdateUrlHistory />
    <BootstrapperUrlHistory />
    <ErrorReportUrlHistory />
    <FallbackCulture>en-US</FallbackCulture>
    <VerifyUploadedFiles>false</VerifyUploadedFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please add the content of the csproj file.

Comment: Done I add it in text file link

Comment: could you please include it directly in your post? External file sharing sites are an issue if the file gets taken down.

Comment: @Aaron can you check please I edit the question add .csproj code.

Comment: You had a old project and VS tried to update to latest version and failed in the middle of the update and quit.  Now you have some files that were updated and other that didn't get updated.  I would compare the .csproj file of and updated project with the one that didn't get updated.  The .csproj file is Xml format and is valid but does not meet the schema for latest version.  Error indicates the .csproj file is the old format from 1.0 or 1.2 VS.

Comment: so what should I have to do now ?

Comment: What does the other csproj files look like?  I want to make sure that solution will work with the version of Net and VS that is installed on your machine.  Try to make the project file look like other project files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem solution.

> **`Before Start applying the steps read them all first.`**

1. Create new project and make sure its run without any problems.
2. On project name right-click unload the project.
3. On project name right-click Edit .csproj .
4. Open your damaged project in another visual studio window .
5. Save a copy from your damaged project .csproj .
6. Repeat steps No 2,3.
7. Compare the xml code and you will see some different codes edit damaged and make it like the new project.
8. Reload the project.